# Submitting form does not behave as expected

Tags: angular

I am currently haunting another bug as I noticed that the form I am using calls on both buttons the `onSubmitClicked()` function:

Originally it looked like this:

```xml
<button mat-raised-button (click)="onBackClicked()">
  Back
</button>
<button mat-raised-button type="submit">
  Submit
</button>
```

No matter which button I am clicking, both call `onSubmitClicked()`. Just the "Back" button call `onBackClicked()` first. Removing the `type="submit"` from the "Submit" button does not change anything.

```xml
<form [formGroup]="placeInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitClicked()">

  <div>
    <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name"/>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="onBackClicked()">
      Back
    </button>
    <button mat-raised-button>
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

The submit function:

```js
onBackClicked() {
  console.log('onBackClicked()')
}

onSubmitClicked() {
  console.log('onSubmitClicked()');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `<button>` inside the `<form>` will try to submit the form unless specified explicitly.

Try this:

```xml
<button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="onBackClicked()">
  Back
</button>
```

Comment: Yes! source: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element